# Max, count on Isar collection

Tags: flutter, nosql, flutter-isar

Normally in a traditional database I would do something like the following to get a count of orders grouped by the Id of the customers (highest at the top). Is this possible in Isar?

```
SELECT TOP (200) Id, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM   Orders
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

```
final query = _isarService.isar.orders
    .filter()
    .customerIdEqualTo(customerId);
```

Not sure what I would do next?

Answer (score 0):

you can use queryBuilder

some thing like this may help you

```
final donors = await isar.donorModels
        .buildQuery<DonorModel>(
          limit: limit,
          filter: const FilterCondition.equalTo(
            property: r'customerId',
            value: customerId,
          ),
          
        )
        .findAll();
```